# Redux Thunk + Axios "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I've been looking through similar problem/solutions on stackoverflow for hours but none of them seem to be solving my problem. Basically I am trying to setup Redux Thunk in order to make API calls in my action as follows:

```
export function loadUserInfo(){
    return function(dispatch){
        return axios.get('/api/auth/GetUsername', config).then(response=>{
        dispatch(loadUserSuccess(response.data.username));
    }).catch(function(error){
        throw(error);
    });
};
```

I've tried with and without the return statement before "axios", however I keep getting the following error:

> "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

I belieive I've configured my middleware correctly:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState){
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant())
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with formatting; you're trying to catch the failed promise on the returned thunk.

```
export function loadUserInfo(){
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get('/api/auth/GetUsername', config)
            .then(response => dispatch(loadUserSuccess(response.data.username)))
            .catch(error => throw(error))
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch(loadUserSuccess(response.data.username))
```

- you are passing a function loadUserSuccess to dispatch ,So loadUserSuccess must return a object .
- `loadUserSuccess(response){
  return {type:"success", payload:response}
  }`
- Something like that.Through this reducer will able to know which action has been dispatched .